# How to mock a void method with no arguments?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

For Example:

```
Class A{

    string s = null;
    public void method(){

        s="Sample String";

    }
}
```

I have a void method with similar scenario. How can I test such void method?

Comment: But what behavior is it that you are trying to test?

Comment: for void methods we test test whether internal calls are happening with specified parameters and if parameter is object type, we can even verify one or more property of that object. As Nikosi mention, you need to tell more on what exact methon you want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `void` methods you should test the interaction with its dependent objects within the `void` method. I think a `void` method with no argument is rarely useful to test (but if you have a valid use case, please add it to your question). I provided you a simple example for a method **with** an argument but `void` as a return type:

```
public class A {

  private DatabaseService db;
  private PaymentService payment;

  // constructor

  public void doFoo() {
    if(n < 2) {
      db.updateDatabase();
    } else {
      payment.payBill();
    }
  }

}
```

And the unit test for this can look like the following

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

   @Mock
   DatabaseService db;

   @Mock
   PaymentService payment;

   @Test
   public void testDoFooWithNGreaterTwo() {
     A cut = new A(db, payment); // cut -> class under test
     cut.doFoo(3);
     verify(payment).payBill(); // verify that payment was called
   }

   @Test
   public void testDoFooWithNLessThanTwo() {
     A cut = new A(db, payment); // cut -> class under test
     cut.doFoo(1);
     verify(db).updateDatabase(); // verify that db was called
   }

}
```